# Html/Css flickering when i hover over a button

Tags: html, css, hover

i've been looking for some solutions here but i seem to stupid to change it the way i need to, so i decided to make a post.
Following problem:

```css
button {
  font-family: custom-bold;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.322);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

button:hover {
  background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: inline-block;
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;

  color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
  
}
```

```html
<button>thatsabutton</button>
```

when u hover over it, it flickers. When for example i add a margin-top to it with 1%, i would prevent the flickering but it would fk over with the other things i've made. Any idea what i can do it to prvent it with out adding margin to it? Regards!

Comment: What do you mean by flickers? I dont see any difference when I add the margin-top to it

Comment: Thats how it normally looks on my side https://puu.sh/FNvzw.gif
and when i add a margin it goes down to the bottom like that https://puu.sh/FNvAj.gif which is not what i want

Comment: just to understand your problem? does this fiddle flicker? https://jsfiddle.net/6Lxdytej/

Comment: It does not,now im hella confused why it's flickering on my side when i use the botton anywhere on my project

Comment: do you really need `perspective` / transform on hover? Sometimes it causes weird render issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only transitioning the color, change it to 'all' and you're OK.
Also add it to the button class for the reverse action.

```css
button {
  font-family: custom-bold;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.322);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: inline-block;
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;

  color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
  
}
```

```html
<button>thatsabutton</button>
```